# Drag and Drop doesnt work in Customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, drag-and-drop, coordinates, customtkinter

I am trying to create a simple drag and drop mechanic that lets you click and drag widgets around the screen with tkinter. (I used the code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGmMsGOcBB0)

```
import tkinter as tk

def drag_start(event):
    label.startX = event.x
    label.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    x = label.winfo_x() - label.startX + event.x
    y = label.winfo_y() - label.startY + event.y
    label.place(x=x, y=y)

window = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(window, bg_color="red", width=10, height=5)
label.place(x=0, y=0)

label.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
label.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)

window.mainloop()
```

This works as intended and is using default tkinter widgets.
However when I try to switch out the tkinter widgets for customtkinter widgets:

```
import customtkinter as ctk

def drag_start(event):
    label.startX = event.x
    label.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    x = label.winfo_x() - label.startX + event.x
    y = label.winfo_y() - label.startY + event.y
    label.place(x=x, y=y)

window = ctk.CTk()

label = ctk.CTkLabel(window, bg_color="red", width=10, height=5)
label.place(x=0, y=0)

label.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
label.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)

window.mainloop()
```

...the coordinates seem to work differently all of a sudden or something, since the widgets dont stay under the mouse and the positioning is completely off. (Its a bit hard to explain :) just copy paste the code and try it out)

So if anybody knows in which way customtkinter works different to default tkinter
or has any other ideas for a simple drag and drop mechanic, it would be much appreciated :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It works well on customtkinter 5.2.2 and Python 3.12.1.

Answer (score 0):

The `CTkLabel` class is a descendent of `tk.Frame` with a `tk.Label` attribute called `text_label`. When you bind to `CTkLabel`, the binding is passed to the underlying `tk.Frame`. Because the frame is filled by the label, the click and drag events go to the label, not the frame, so nothing happens. To fix this, bind to the `text_label` instead:

```
label.text_label.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
label.text_label.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
```

This is fixed in version 5.0.0 ([issue](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/65#issuecomment-1333655418)).

Comment: Maybe im interpreting your answer wrong but when I use your two lines and try to bind to the text_label it just says: AttributeError: 'CTkLabel' object has no attribute 'text_label'. Also the problem is not that nothing happens. The widget just doesnt stay with the mouse cursor.

Comment: Which version are you using? (add `print(ctk.__version__)` after your import to check)

Comment: I also tried it with other ctk widgets like a simple CTkFrame and got the same problem.

Comment: Im using 5.2.2.

Comment: Your original code works for me in 5.2.2, which OS are you using?

Comment: The original ctk-code? Im on win11

Comment: Yeah, the ctk code. I'm on win10 but I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've just tested it on win11 and I can't see any difference between the dragging behaviours. You could try binding to `label._label` instead but I don't think that will make much difference.

Comment: This will result in the OP's code moving the inner label rather than the whole CTk widget (frame + label).